# How to efficiently have 1 html layout page for many products that'll call mysql database for product info and insert where I designate it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Ok so eventually I will have let's say 100 products in mysql database. The product page pulls all info from database (such as partnumber, material, color, etc...) and inputs it into the areas of the page that I designate it, all this using php. The previous page will show all 100 products and when user click's on one product it'll go to that product page. Just like all websites right...

I don't believe I need to make 100 individual html pages for each product right? Can I make just 1 main html page that is the templet for the 100 different products? Basically when user clicks the image tag of the product(1st example of code) it'll open the main html templet but somehow call to the database on open and load that specific info? Then other products will have the same process but for they're specific data from database. The 1st sample code is one product on the page that'll display all 100 products with the href containing the image that'll get clicked to show user actual product page retrieved dynamically without page reload, into a predestined section. I'm sure there is a name for what I'm looking to do but all the research I've done I haven't found what I'm looking for. Is there a better way then what I'm explaining? Also I hope this makes sense, Thank you for any input.

```
<td><a href="pageContent.php"><img class="td-Image" src="image.jpg"></a>
 </td>
 <td class="td-manufacturer">
   <h6>MANUFACTURER</h6>
   <p>Lowes</p>
 </td>
 <td class="td-addComponent">
   <p>$104.99</p>
   <a href="#"><button class="add-button">ADD</button></a>
 </td>
 <td class="td-material">
   <h6>MATERIAL</h6>
   <p>Aluminum 7075-t6 Forged</p>
 </td> 
 <td class="td-platform">
   <h6>PLATFORM</h6>
   <p>Large</p>
 </td>
 <td class="td-america">
   <h6>AMERICAN MADE</h6>
   <p>YES</p>
 </td>
```

Actual product page where php gets info from database example

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

<div class="description">
  <h3>Descrption</h3>
  <p>
    <?php 
     echo $row['Description'];
    ?>
  </p>
</div>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

> Editor Note: I edited the question to reflect what he want based on thread on my answer below.

Comment: best place to start with https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Add an unique Id to your products in your mysql database, using the Auto Increment option (A_I checkbox in phpmyadmin). Then you can pass that id into a link to the product page ```href=“individualProduct.php?id=” while rendering all the products on the all products page.

Then in individualProduct.php you can get that id and retrieve the data

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE id =?”;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($_GET[“id”]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// Do stuff with $result as it is the individual product corresponding to that id
```

Comment: Sorry... correction on the "SELECT * FROM AR15Parts" Supposed to been just "Parts". Thanks

Comment: ok so what I'm having trouble understanding is how to pass the 'id' into the link  and retrieving on the other page which is pageContent.php for the individual product info. I have actually coded my sql database so that the products have a PartsID column with 'id' of 1 and 2 and are the Primary key, should work by that right?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you would need to pass in a unique identifier i.e product-id and create a query to fetch from the database product info by product-id

```
$product-id= $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AR15Parts WHERE id='$product-id'";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error(); 
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

//display your data

if($row){
  echo $row['field']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimally, you'll need 2 files:

- index/list of products
- detail information of the selected product

### index files (maybe call it `index.php`)

Here, you need to select products and make it a list:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Parts");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:loadDetail(\'' . $row['id'] . '\')">' . $row['name']."</a><br />\n";
}
```

Since you want the detail to be shown to the index/list page, let's add a container area:

```
<div id="container-detail">

</div>
```

Add a little javascript code to handle AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDetail(itemId){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://website.address/path/to/detail.php?id=" + itemId, true);
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)  
            {
                document.getElementById("container-detail").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }

        xhr.send();

    }
</script>
```

### detail page (let's call it `detail.php`)

In this screen, we fetch details for only one part, specified by [HTTP GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get) `id` parameter. The one that's being supplied from `index.php` (the `?id=` part).

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");

$part = $stmt->fetch();

echo "Name: " . $part['name'] . "<br />\n";
echo "Manufacturer: " . $part['manufacturer'] . "<br />\n";
echo "Price: " . $part['price'] . "<br />\n";
```

That's it, you should get it working with a few adjustments based on the table and template you have.

A little note is that I used [PDO mechanism](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples) to do the query. This is because [mysql_* function has been deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for so long that it is now removed from PHP 7.0. Also, the current PHP version has been PHP 8. So, be prepared, a lot of web hosting might gonna remove older PHP versions, moving forward.

Comment: ok so I was trying to follow what you had suggested. I changed my connection to PDO type, took me some time to get the page to just come back like before with the new PDO code. So I have a content.php file that is the list of 100 products which you said lets call it "index.php". I'm a little confused on how to make the <td><a href="pageContent.php"><img class="td-Image" src="image.jpg"></a>
 </td> onclick load pageContent.php and pull the row specific to the product, and it'll fill the areas like above where you echoed out name, manufacturer, price. Bangin head on desk! Thanks

Comment: Ah, so you're using javascript async loading request (or better known as AJAX)? If that's the case, that would be a whole lot different question than what you have here.

Comment: yes thats possible, I only said onclick because to me it seems when the user clicks the href that has the img tag in it, it would load the product page then pull data from data and input into the areas I want, and so the same for the 100 other products but they're info instead, and only use 1 html template for the products pages.  So is it a complex javascript that would run this, or javascript plus php? And like I had said before, I think, I was successful in just the product page pulling the data to the page directly with PDO. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: may I update your question to reflect this new information? so that I can answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes please and thanks

Comment: would the itemId you placed in this function "function loadDetail(itemId)" be the name of the column in database where the ids are at? Thanks

Comment: no, it's just javascript variable you set to query through AJAX. This variable is received by PHP via `?id={{itemId}}` HTTP parameter that you read using `$_GET['id']` in PHP.